# How to get rid off newlines from a text file and replace them with commas?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning python in school and teacher ask us to do something like this and I don't know how to do it. I have a text file that look like this.

```
23 
46 
14
```

I need to read those lines form the file and print them like this

```
23,46,14
```

I have found this but i don't know how to use this to make something that i need.

```
string_without_line_breaks = ""
for line in a_file:
  stripped_line = line.rstrip()
  string_without_line_breaks += stripped_line
a_file.close()

print(string_without_line_breaks)
```

output of code above is

```
234614
```

so It's almost what i want but i don't know how to get commas into it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: all you need to do is `string_without_line_breaks += ","` after you add each line

Answer (score 1):

```
a_file = open('your_file.txt', 'r')
string_with_breaks = а_file.read()
a_file.close()

string_without_line_breaks = string_with_breaks.replace('\n', ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use strip() just replace newline with comma. Change this:

```
stripped_line = line.rstrip()
```

to this:

```
stripped_line = line.replace('\n', ',')
```

Comment: You should still strip it before replacing newlines so you don't have a trailing comma.